# Finding a continuous function and a sequentially compact

Tags: functions, compactness

Is there such a continuous function $f: R\rightarrow R $ and a sequentially compact $K \subset R$ such that the inverse $f^{-1}(K)$ is not sequentially compact?

Could someone provide me with some examples so I can get a better understanding of sequentially compact?

Comment: Any periodic continuous function will do, e.g., $f(x)=\sin x$.

Comment: okay, so lets say we let $f(x)=sin(x)$. Then what would be an example of a K that would work here? $K=[-\pi / 2, \pi \ 2]$?

Comment: Why not just use $K=\{0\}$? Then $f^{-1}[K]=\{n\pi:n\in\Bbb Z\}$, which is certainly not sequentially compact.

Answer (score -2):

**Hint:** If you choose sin x as your function what would you choose for $K$? $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$?